# left and right shoulders are asymmetrical

Tags: exercise-technique, shoulders, muscle-recovery, chest, muscle-imbalance

My left and right shoulders are asymmetrical. My left shoulder seems attached with my upper chest perfectly whereas my right shoulder and upper chest has a gap between them. How can i make them equal? Are there any exercises to build the gap between the upper chest and shoulder near the collar bone?

Comment: Do you have any injuries in those areas?